# openpgp.initWorker is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openpgp.js

Please help...I am trying to get [openPGP.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) working in an existing ASP.Net MVC Web Application.

I first started by adding the following html script tags:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/openpgp.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/openpgp.worker.min.js")"></script>
```

and I got this error on loading my page:

> ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined

So I did some research and added RequireJS to my page, like so:
`<script data-main='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/openpgp.min.js")'  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/require.js")"></script>`

Then in the event handler in which I intend to run my decryption logic, I have the following code:

```
async function decryptBBRecording(commId) {
        var openpgp = require(['openpgp']);
        await openpgp.initWorker({ path: 'openpgp.worker.js' }) // set the relative web worker path
...
...
...
}
```

and it is on that "await" line that I am getting

> TypeError: openpgp.initWorker is not a function

I'm thinking this is because I have not loaded the openpgp.worker.min.js file.  But when I do so via script tag, I get the following errors:

> ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined

and when I do so via `require(["@Url.Content("~/Scripts/openpgp.worker.min.js")"]);` I get this:

> Error: Script error for "openpgp"
>   ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined

Please can you provide me with guidance on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided [here](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues/915#issuecomment-505405625).

You don't have to include `openpgp.worker.min.js` on the page directly. You also shouldn't need `require.js` and the call to `require`. Just include `openpgp.min.js` on the page, it will globally define `openpgp`, and then call `openpgp.initWorker` as you are doing.